# can't display backend errors in component html - Angular

Tags: angular, observable, angular-observable, angular-errorhandler

I'm trying to display the backend error that I generate with my errorHandler, but it's not showing anything.

How can I show it?

it returns `undefined`

**HTML**

```
 //This triggers the observable, if it has an error it sets that error to the variable backendError 
    {{(pickupAvailabilityList$ | async)}} 

    {{ backendError}}
```

**COMPONENT TS**

```
getPickupAvailability(
    equipmentLookup: EquipmentID[]
  ): Observable<PickupAvailability[]> {
    this.backendError = this.pickupAvailabilityService.getErrorMessage();
    return this.pickupAvailabilityService.getAmountDue(equipmentLookup);
}
```

**SERVICE TS** The console log  in `getErrors()` gives me `undefined`

```
getAmountDue(equipmentID: EquipmentID[]): Observable<PickupAvailability[]> {
    this.errorHandler.errorMessages = '';
    return this.http
      .post<PickupAvailability>(
        this.BASE_URL + this.AMOUNT_DUE_URL,
        equipmentID
      )
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler.handleError));
  }

  getErrorMessage(): string {
    this.errorMessage = this.errorHandler.errorMessages;
    return this.errorHandler.errorMessages;
}
```

**ERROR HANDLER SERVICE TS** The console log get printed

```
handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    // To know the version of RxJS npm list --depth=0
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred: ', error.error.message);
      this.errorMessages =
        error.error.message;
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}` + ` body was: ${error.message}`
      );
      this.errorMessages =
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}` + ` body was: ${error.message}`;
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return _throw('Something bad happened; please try again later.');
}
```

Comment: When do you call this function? Make sure you `subscribe` to your Observable.

Comment: @Tommy I have this `(pickupAvailabilityList$ | async)` in the same HTML page which should trigger the observable that calls the api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like:

```
 .pipe(catchError((err,caught)=>{
     return this.errorHandler.handleError();
  }));
```

So that your `handleError` method does not lose the context of the service it is defined in.